# ANTLR tree parser grammar rewrite rule for *

Tags: java, antlr, dsl, parser-generator

I have a tree grammar, part of the grammar is shown below

```
transitions
    :'transitions' '=' INT ('(' INT ',' INT ')') + ';' -> ^(TRANSITIONS INT INT INT*)
    ;
```

and here is the respective part of the tree parser grammar,

```
transitions
    :^(TRANSITIONS INT INT INT*)
    {System.out.println("");}
    ;
```

I have used + rewrite rule and that is basically repitition. In the grammar above, the user is entering minimum 3 integer values, say
one possible input,

```
  transitions 1 (5,0)
```

2nd possible input

```
transitions 2 (5,0) (5,1)
```

3rd possible input

```
transitions 3 (5,0) (5,1) (5,2)
```

and so on.
The first integer determines how many pairs of integers there will be. The problem is how will I access these integer inputs in my parser grammar and how can I possibly print these in the println statement above?

Please refer to my question [ANTLR java test file can't create object of tree grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012371/antlr-java-test-file-cant-create-object-of-tree-grammar) for the complete grammar I have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you keep the "pairs" of numbers in a separate rule:

### parser grammar

```
transitions
 : 'transitions' '=' INT pair+ ';' -> ^(TRANSITIONS INT pair+)
 ;

pair
 : '(' INT ',' INT ')' -> ^(PAIR INT INT)
 ;
```

### tree grammar

```
transitions
 : ^(TRANSITIONS INT pair+) {System.out.println("transitions.INT=" + $INT.text);}
 ;

pair
 : ^(PAIR a=INT b=INT) {System.out.println("pair=" + $a.text + ", " + $b.text);}
 ;
```

### EDIT

A quick demo:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
  TRANSITIONS;
  PAIR;
}

parse
 : transitions EOF!
   {
     CommonTree root = $transitions.tree;

     int count = root.getChildCount();

     Tree child1 = root.getChild(0);
     Tree child2 = root.getChild(1);
     Tree child3 = root.getChild(2);
     Tree child4 = root.getChild(3);

     System.out.println("root=" + root.getToken().getText() + " has " + count + " child nodes:");
     System.out.println(" - child1=" + child1.toStringTree());
     System.out.println(" - child2=" + child2.toStringTree());
     System.out.println(" - child3=" + child3.toStringTree());
     System.out.println(" - child4=" + child3.toStringTree());

     String secondValueFromLastPair = child4.getChild(1).getText();
     System.out.println("\nsecondValueFromLastPair=" + secondValueFromLastPair);
   }
 ;

transitions
 : 'transitions' '=' INT pair+ ';' -> ^(TRANSITIONS INT pair+)
 ;

pair
 : '(' INT ',' INT ')' -> ^(PAIR INT INT)
 ;

INT   : '0'..'9'+;
SPACE : ' ' {skip();};
```

If you now parse the input `"transitions = 3(5,0) (5,1) (5,2);"`, you'd see the following being printed to the console:

```
root=TRANSITIONS has 4 child nodes:
 - child1=3
 - child2=(PAIR 5 0)
 - child3=(PAIR 5 1)
 - child4=(PAIR 5 1)

secondValueFromLastPair=2
```

Comment: Onething, I would like to ask,
^(PAIR a=INT b=INT)
a and b are the labels?
Yes it works fine but if I give the following input, say.
transitions = 3(5,0)  (5,1) (5,2);
How will I store it so that my AST contain
PAIR0 = (5,0)
PAIR1 = (5,1)
PAIR2 = (5,2)

Comment: @RizwanAbbasi, it's already stored like that. The `transitions` rule produces an AST of type [CommonTree](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1tree_1_1_common_tree.html) whose root is `TRANSITIONS` and will have 4 child-nodes (also `CommonTree`'s): an `INT` and 3 `PAIR` nodes.

Comment: If I print AST, I get,
(PROT test) (INITIALP 5) (PROC 4) (TRANSITIONS 3 (PAIR 5 0) (PAIR 5 1) (PAIR 5 2))
You can see that I can't differentiate among pairs.
In the java code above(where you printed),  how would I access integers in the following manner(somehow)
PAIR0(g0, a0) PAIR1(g1,a1) PAIR2(g2, a2)
Thank you

Comment: @RizwanAbbasi, of course you can: the tree is `(TRANSITIONS 3 (PAIR 5 0) (PAIR 5 1) (PAIR 5 2))`, so the AST with root `TRANSITIONS` has 4 child nodes: `3`, `(PAIR 5 0)`, `(PAIR 5 1)` and `(PAIR 5 2)`. Now all you need to do is look at the API to see how you can get a hold of the children of nodes (hint: I posted a link to the `CommonTree` API in my previous comment). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind support.

Comment: Thank you so much for the EDIT as well.

Comment: @RizwanAbbasi, feel free to create a new question.